# Python Socket: Server side not responding after the input of list

Tags: python, sockets

So far, this program has been sending messages from the client to the server and back several times. However, when '200 Roll Dice' is entered from the client side,and is processed in the server side, i.e. producing a list. it doesn't send the information(list) back to the client. Instead it just stops.

For example: from connected  user: 200 Roll Dice
             [1, 5, 2, 3, 3]
- It just stops responding from this point. I can't seem to determine the problem.

Below is the snippet of the code:

```
def Main():
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 5010

    mySocket = socket.socket()
    mySocket.bind((host,port))

    mySocket.listen(3)
    conn, addr = mySocket.accept()
    print ("Connection from: " + str(addr))
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
        if not data:
                                        break
        print ("from connected  user: " + str(data))

        diceRoll = rollDice() # rollDice function produces a list of random numbers


        if data == '200 Roll Dice':
            dicedata = input(diceRoll)
            conn.send(dicedata.encode())
        else:
            data = input(" ? ")
            conn.send(data.encode())


    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if data == '200 Roll Dice':
    dicedata = input(diceRoll)
    conn.send(dicedata.encode())
```

You are showing a list as a prompt text, instead of sending it back to the client. 
You should do the following:

```
if data == '200 Roll Dice':
    conn.send(str(diceRoll).encode())
```

This will send a list (as a *string*) back to the client. If you want to send it as a *list* - you should use *pickle* module.

Answer (score 0):

`input()` is completely useless in this function. It requires an input from user and the args is what the console show to the user to explain what the program is looking for, like the example below (done on python console):

```
>>> name = input('Insert your name: ')
Insert your name: Ezio
>>> name
'Ezio'
```

Assuming that parameters that would be sent back to the client are a string "?" and the result of rollDice() function, you should write like this your if-else statement:

```
    if data == '200 Roll Dice':
        dicedata = diceRoll
        conn.send(dicedata.encode())
    else:
        data = " ? "
        conn.send(data.encode())
```

Far even better would be if you declare a return variable and you also edit his value:

```
    ret = ""
    if data == '200 Roll Dice':
        ret = diceRoll
    else:
        ret = " ? "
    conn.send(ret.encode())
```